# RSpec triggering after_save callback on in memory instance of object creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

When I am testing for a particular project I create a new instance of an ActiveRecord object using

```
ObjectType.new(parameters)
```

This instantiation in RSpec 3.3 (the latest version) calls the after_save callback within that model though. This behavior does not match what actually happens in the development environment and what I expect when that new instance in memory is created. Additionally if I do a binding.pry on the test that this is ran on I can examine the database and in fact there is a persisted object in the database that is created by RSpec instead of just using the in memory object.

Why is this behavior occurring and how should I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

So it appears that if you have a dependency object that relies on the in memory ActiveRecord object and then that object is saved to the database, the in memory object will also be saved.

For example.

```
obj = ObjectType.new(parameters)
DependencyObject.create(relies_on: obj)
```

The `obj` object will be persisted to the database first and then the DependencyObject will be saved.

Comment: Can you show some of the code you're actually calling? Unless you overrode the initializer for the ActiveRecord class then I'm willing to bet there's another line of code in something like a before block that is calling save on this object or doing a create somewhere.

Comment: Ah! I think I found it. It appears that when dependency objects are saved, if they have a dependency on an object in ActiveRecord that is in memory that object will also be saved to the database. This seems to be my problem, I have other dependencies that get created and saved to the database and they save the object that I only create in memory. I have updated my question with what I believe is the problem.

Comment: Looks like you've answered your question. In stead of putting it in your question, why not create an Answer so that people know that there is a solution to this problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that if you have a dependency object that relies on the in memory ActiveRecord object and then that object is saved to the database, the in memory object will also be saved.

For example.

```
obj = ObjectType.new(parameters)
DependencyObject.create(relies_on: obj)
```

The `obj` object will be persisted to the database first and then the `DependencyObject` will be saved. This can lead to very strange callback behavior if you have a callback on `obj` on after_create or something it will get called at the execution of the save for `DependencyObject` and then the save for the other object will occur. Can be very frustrating.